# Validate richfaces:dataTable against no data

Tags: validation, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I would like to validate my richfaces:datatable component against empty.
In other words I  have `<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" ...>` and list must have at least one element.
Is there some good sollution for this kind of validation.

Regards,
A

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a validator for this. It's for submitted request parameters only. If the sole purpose is to display some message when the list is empty, then just use the `rendered` attribute.

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">
    ...
</rich:dataTable>
<h:outputText value="List is empty!" rendered="#{empty bean.list}" />
```

---

**Update**: the table seems to be part of a form. Best what you could do is to add a `FacesMessage` yourself in the bean's action method.

```
public String submit() {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
            new FacesMessage("Please add at least one item"));
        return null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

with a

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

which shows only messages with a `null` client ID.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have to also block the further form processing, so showing message does not solve the thing:(

Comment: Fine, but this requires to implement the code for every list. What if I would like to add some size validation on jsf page. I have a lot of datatables in my pageflow and some of them requires at least one element. Is it really the only solution to mess with submit every time we want to change this requirement?